# free data asynchronously in c++

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I get a data structure like this:

```
struct My_data
{
  MyArray<float> points;
  MyArray<float> normals;
  MyArray<float> uvCoords;
};
```

This function can be used to free them:

```
void ClearAlembicData(My_data* myData)
{
  myData->points.clear();
  myData->normals.clear();
  myData->uvCoords.clear();
}
```

I want to asynchronously clean the myData so that the program will not wait util all the xxx.clear() are done. Here is my actual code:

```
My_data myData;
myData.point.push_back(point);
myData.nomals.push_back(nomals);
myData.uvCorrds.push_back(uvCorrds);

ClearAlembicData(&myData);

myData.point.push_back(point);
myData.nomals.push_back(nomals);
myData.uvCorrds.push_back(uvCorrds);
```

Could you show me how to do it in C++? thanks

Comment: Just create a new `My_data` instance and you can clear the old one in all the time you want.

Comment: How is `MyArray` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions, implement `MyArray::swap(MyArray&)`. Then

```
void ClearAlembicData(My_data* myData)
{
  MyArray<float> old_points;
  MyArray<float> old_normal;
  MyArray<float> old_coords;

  // Fast swap, myData arrays become empty
  myData->points.swap(old_points);
  myData->normals.clear(old_normals);
  myData->uvCoords.clear(old_coords);

  // Assumed to be passed to async function
  old_points.clear();
  old_normals.clear();
  old_coords.clear();
}
```

There is no enough information about `MyArray` abilities, such as support of move semantics, a real function clear, thus this is just an idea.

Comment: Thanks, there is already a swap implemented. Since I need to use myData globally,  your answer helps alot.

Comment: Typo: double deleting, instead of swapping. CTRL+V addiction hurts.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the definition of `MyArray`, this will either cause undefined behavior or be completely pointless.

If the container is thread-safe, it will block your `push_back` while the `clear` is being executed in the other thread (making the 'clearing it asynchronously' completely pointless), if it is not, you are introducing a race condition, which might even end up crashing your program, because you would be concurrently manipulating a shared resource. (Not a good idea).

If you still want to do it, here is a way that might work:

1. Make 'myData' into a pointer and operate on that.
2. Upon wanting to clear, store that pointer in another pointer variable and replace the pointer with `new My_Data`.
3. Pass the stored pointer to your asynchronous 'free' function.
4. Continue to work with your new data structure in the original thread.

This way, you are not working on a shared resource and asynchronous freeing becomes feasible.

As for 'how to', if you've got C++11, something like this would work (Pseudo-Code).

```
My_data *myData = new My_data();
myData->point.push_back(point);
myData->nomals.push_back(nomals);
myData->uvCorrds.push_back(uvCorrds);

std::thread([=](){ ClearAlembicData(myData); delete myData; }).detach();

myData = new My_data()
myData->point.push_back(point);
myData->nomals.push_back(nomals);
myData->uvCorrds.push_back(uvCorrds);

delete myData;
```

Comment: It's preferrable to use move semantics. Raw pointers are rarely a good option. If `MyArray` implements move constructor/move assignment, you even get this for free. If not, using `std::unique_ptr` is still preferrable, e.g. `auto v = std::make_unique<std::vector<int>>(100, 1);
    std::thread t([](std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>&& vec) { vec.reset(); }, std::move(v));
    t.join();`

Answer (score 0):

If `MyArray` is a wrapper around `std::vector`, know that the `clear()` operation is O(1) as `float` is trivially destructible and the compiler can eliminate the loop that destroys elements individually.

If it is not, consider implementing `MyArray.clear()` such that it marks the container as having a non-zero capacity yet zero contents. As stated above, `std::vector` accomplishes this by simply setting `slots_available = capacity`.